# style.display="block" no longer working once moving my code to neocities.org off of VScode

Tags: javascript, html

So, I coded in a section of my project in which one image/link is hidden until the user goes to multiple other links and then back. When I open in live server from my computer, the javascript does exactly as it needs to do. Keeps the object hidden until these three links have been visited. I recently transferred over my code to neocities as I am hosting my project there, and I cannot figure out what the problem is. The system records a list of the links you visit, and I checked and it does output a list, but it will not perform the actions needed when this list is created.

I tried to switch between calling it hidden or block or none and removing the style display, yet nothing seems to work.

`places.js`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let page = String(window.location.pathname);
    //collects path in current window
    let list = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("list") || "[]");
    //list for every page visited in local storage

    if (!list.includes(page)) { 
        list.push(page)
        window.localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list))
        //if page is not in list, it is now added to list.
    }

    if (list.includes("/clocktower/clocktower") && list.includes("/stables/stables") && list.includes("/bank/bank")) {
        //checks list if three locations are there, if they are....reveals cemetery
        document.getElementById("hiddenlink").style.display="block";
        window.alert("Odd. Had I noticed that before?");
    }

    if (list.includes("/cemetery/cemetery")) {
        /* this will reset the list once cemetery is visited*/
        window.localStorage.setItem("list", "[]");
        document.getElementById("hiddenlink").style.display="none";
        
    }

})
```

Using `window.alert(list);` will produce something such as: `/opening/places,/bank/bank,/clocktower/clocktower,/stables/stables`

`places.html` (section is `div class="cemetery"` which is what I want to be hidden until the `sections:clocktower`, bank, and stables have all been visited. It works fine through my own live server, but after I uploaded it to an actual site, it cannot execute it. I think the problem is that is not looking through the list to see what it includes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head> 
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>San Roque, California</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/misc/favicon.PNG">
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  </head>


    <body>
      <div class="background">
        <div class ="inside">
          <div class="places">
            <div class="stables">
                  <a href="/stables/stables.html"><img src="stable.png" height="180"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="cemetery">
                  <a href="/cemetery/cemetery.html" id="hiddenlink" style="display: none;"><img src="graveyard.png" height="220"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="clocktower">
                  <a href="/clocktower/clocktower.html"><img src="clocktower.png" height="350"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="bankstore">
              <img src="bankstore.png" usemap="#image-map" height = 200>
                  <map name="image-map">
                  <area target="" alt="bank" title="bank" href="/bank/bank.html" coords="0,0,165,200" shape="rect">
                  <area target="" alt="store" title="store" href="/store/store.html" coords="165,200,337s,0" shape="rect">
                   </map>
            </div>
            <div class="saloon">
                <a href="/saloon/saloon.html"><img src="saloon.png" height="200"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="office">
                <a href="/office/office.html"><img src="sheriff.png" height="200"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  <script src="places.js"> 
 </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

additional image for reference of the list output being made
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIfhd.png)

Comment: so is it `.style.display="block";` doesn't work, or that `list.includes("/clocktower/clocktower") && list.includes("/stables/stables") && list.includes("/bank/bank")` is false? or that `list.includes("/cemetery/cemetery")` is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a typo in [`places.js`](https://sanroquecalifornia.neocities.org/opening/places.js) (and not your submission), where you're looking for `list.includes("clocktower/clocktower")` which is never satisfied, even when you visit the clock tower page (which pushes `/clocktower/clocktower`, with the leading slash)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had completely thought I was going mad looking over everything but that singular slash!

Comment: Best to paste exactly what you've done, then someone on SO could have found the issue. The code you've posted works as you expect. I guess I'm confused how your local `places.js` and the neocities `places.js` could even differ (if you uploaded the file directly)